# Regex Or Expression , Python

Tags: python, regex

I have many sentences and i need to have a regex expression that accounts for extracting "5th layout" and "balaji layout" . To simply put it as a word followed by layout and combination of digit-word with layout."text2 is a string".
 This code below gives me the regex "balaji layout" as required.

```
import re
p = re.compile('\w+\slayout')
q = re.search(p,text2)
q.group()
```

To account for digits, i added an OR but this just gives me "i layout" (for balaji)

```
import re
p = re.compile('(\w+|\d\w+)\slayout')
q = re.search(p,text2)
q.group()
```

How do i account for both with proper extraction ??

Comment: You need to provide a sample text to parse, and the desired output. But I think your problem is you are missing a `+`

Comment: Just try swapping them `(\d\w+|\w+)`, for your case that should work :)

Comment: 1 thing I dont get. `\w` should match digits too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex `(\w|\d\w+)` means `one letter or (one digit and more than one letter)`

You need the following:

```
\d?\w+\slayout
```

Meaning `0 or 1 digit, then 1 or more letters`

Comment: thanks, works fine ..actually a missing + after \w was a typo. could u see and tell me what the problem is in the current code in question??   
'(\w+|\d\w+)\slayout'

Comment: not really sure, actually. My tests show that your first regex (`'\w+\slayout'`) works fine. (as \w matches digits as well)

Comment: possibly has to do with your text. can you post a significant extract of the text ?

Comment: i got it.. re.search matches 1st expression and if its true, it moves to the 2nd. so in my case , the second expression is never reached at all.

Comment: 'house no. 48,49,50,flat no. g2,sathyam shivam apartment,2nd cross,balaji layout,chikka banaswadi,bengaluru-560043'

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
re.compile('(\d[a-zA-Z_]+|[a-zA-Z_]+)\slayout')
```

Answer (score 1):

The most concise pattern that you can use to get *exactly* what you want is:

```
re.compile(r'[a-z0-9]+\slayout', re.I)  # re.I means to ignore the case.
```